# Unable to register VB ocx components (err 0x80040201)

Tags: vb6, windows-xp, ocx

I have a problem trying to register some ocx files.

When I execute regsvr32, it returns 0x80040201 error code. I'm using win xp SP3 and my user has administrator permissions.

When I try to register them with another user on the same machine I can do it without a problem, and both users are administrators and have "total control" permissions over c:\windows\system32

Any clue of what can be going on here?

Comment: Is this ocx related to Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

Could be a [registry permission](http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/ie/11096/0x80040201-after-IE7-Guide-Plus-PanelAd-ocx-refuses-to-regist) error or a [missing dependent dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237191).

[dependswalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can help you figure out which dlls are being used by your ocx file and [processmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) can show you which reg keys are being touched during registration.